# Calling another member function from a function in a class template in C++

Tags: c++, class-template

Let's say I have a class template named `myTemplate` with some member variables and two member functions, `funcTempA`, and `funcTempB`.

```
template <class T>
class myTemplate
{
    private:
        //member variables
    public:
        T* funcTempA(T *arg1, T *arg2);
        T* funcTempB(T *arg1, T *arg2);
}
```

`funcTempB` calls `funcTempA` in its implementation. I just want to know what will be the correct syntax for calling it.

```
template <class T>
T* funcTempB(T *arg1, T *arg2)
{
    //how to call funcTempA here?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call it directly, such as:

```
return funcTempA(arg1, arg2);
```

BTW: The definition of the member function `funcTempB` seems wrong, might cause some unexpected errors.

```
template <class T>
T* myTemplate<T>::funcTempB(T *arg1, T *arg2)
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{
    return funcTempA(arg1, arg2);
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/MJQLR66610)

Comment: The definition of the member function `funcTempB` could be correct if the function were implemented inside the header file directly.

Comment: @ValentinTrinqué No. It'll be a normal(non-member) function. http://rextester.com/ECKC37286

Comment: Well, I meant this way : http://rextester.com/RJA6882 and considering the way you implement `funcTempA`, we were on the same waves.

Comment: @ValentinTrinqué You mean implement inside the class definition? Then can't write `template <class T>` in front of the function definition as OP did, so I guess OP didn't meant this way.

Answer (score 3):

To call a member  variable or a member function, you can use `this` keyword.

```
template <class T>
T* myTemplate<T>::funcTempB(T *arg1, T *arg2)
{
    this->funcTempA(arg1, arg2);
    return ...;
}
```

You can read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) to know ore about `this`

Comment: was the pun intended?

Comment: You nailed this pun :)